# Jump position inside foreach

Tags: php

I have this foreach

```
foreach ($stats as $imageData) {
    $display[$i][0] = "<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><input type = \"checkbox\" id = \"check_" . $imageData["cid"] . "\" name = \"checkbox[]\" class=\"checkbox\" /></p>";
    $display[$i][1] = $imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["name"];
    $display[$i][2] = $imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["color"];
    $display[$i][3] = $imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["size"];
    $i++;
}
```

I want give a limit of images with same size to display.
For example I define limit=2
So only 2 images with the same size will be displayed.

Should I create a var for each size to accumulate times I repeat the same size?

```
EDIT example:
Limit=2
img1 200*200
img2 200*200
img3 200*200
img4 100*500
img5 400*600

I should display:
img1 200*200
img2 200*200
img4 100*500
img5 400*600
```

Comment: Сreate tracking array and count: `ar['200x200'] = 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a limit like this:

```
$limit = 2;
$usedSizes = array();
foreach ($stats as $imageData) {
    $size = json_encode($imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["size"]);
    $usedSizes[$size] = isset($usedSizes[$size]) ? $usedSizes[$size]+1 : 1;
    if ($usedSizes[$size] > $limit) continue; // skip this image
    $display[$i][0] = "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">
                           <input type = \"checkbox\" id = \"check_" . $imageData["cid"] . "\" name = \"checkbox[]\" class=\"checkbox\" /></p>";
    $display[$i][1] = $imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["name"];
    $display[$i][2] = $imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["color"];
    $display[$i][3] = $imageInfo[$imageData["cid"]]["size"];
    $i++;
}
```

JSON is used just to make sure the size attribute is translated to a string. It is not relevant whether this encoding is JSON or not for the working of the code. It just has to be a string that will be equal for equal sizes.

Comment: Perfect $trincot, it works as I want. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you can correct your code in this way:

```
$sizeCheck = array();
foreach( $stats as $imageData )
{
    $key = "{$imageInfo[$imageData[cid]][size][w]}x{$imageInfo[$imageData[cid]][size][h]}";
    if( isset($sizeCheck[$key]) && $sizeCheck[$key]++>1 )
    {
        // Your Code Here
    }

}
```